# How can i include a jsp page depend on the button i choose

Tags: jsp

i have a jsp page call "index.jsp" and create navigation bar like this

```
<div class="nav-in-header" >
        <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="submit" class="nav-item" value="HOME" name="multiPage"/>
        <input type="submit" class="nav-item" value="EXAMPLE" name="multiPage"/>
        <input type="submit" class="nav-item" value="SERVICES" name="multiPage"/>
        <input type="submit" class="nav-item" value="PRODUCTS" name="multiPage"/>
        <input type="submit" class="nav-item" value="CONTACT" name="multiPage"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

when i hit a button "multiPage" parameter will send back to page itself (index.jsp) and depending on the value of the parameter, the div will display a different page.

```
    <%String p = (String)request.getParameter("multiPage");
    %>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${p==null}">
            <jsp:include page="HOME.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${p=='HOME'}">
            <jsp:include page="HOME.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${p=='SERVICES'}">
            <jsp:include page="SERVICES.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${p=='EXAMPLE'}">
            <jsp:include page="EXAMPLE.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${p=='PRODUCTS'}">
            <jsp:include page="PRODUCTS.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${p=='CONTACT'}">
            <jsp:include page="CONTACT.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>

</div>
```

But it do nothing.
So sorry my english is bad :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't you heard about links? That's what should be used in HTML to navigate:

```
<a href="index.jsp?multiPage=HOME">Home</a>
```

Anyway, `${p}` looks for a request (or any other scope) **attribute** named `p`. Not for a local scriptlet variable named `p`.

You should never, ever use scriptlets. Just use

```
<c:when test="${param.multiPage ==' HOME'}">
```

Or, much better, read about MVC, and use an MVC framework instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Wow, i haven't heard about it, but it work. Thank you sir i will read about MVC.

Comment: You should never, ever access jsp directly

Comment: MVC is a good pattern but it's wrong if you use jsp for this. In this way you can't avoid scriptlets.

Comment: @RomanC Where did I recommend using JSPs to implement MVC? I recommended to use an existing MVC framework.

Comment: In your code. You have used jsp to redirect directly. This is wrong. Either you need to change your answer to use MVC or remove it all together.

Comment: No, not at all. The answer starts by explaining why the original code doesn't work and what is the correct code to use to do what the OP wants to do. Then it explains using such code is a bad idea in the first place, and advises using an MVC framework instead. I won't delete a perfectly correct, and accepted answer just because you failed to read the answer correctly, twice.